# Implementing a Tag property on entity classes

Tags: c#, .net, tags, properties

When I create entities in a class library, I tend to add a `Tag` property which may be used by users and extending libraries to store arbitrary data with the object. Now I am looking for the best way to implement such a `Tag` property in my class library, and the reasons why.

In System.Windows.Forms, Microsoft uses `object Tag { get; set; }` as the signature, but it looks too limiting as only one may use the Tag at any time.

I also thought about `HashTable Tag { get; }` to allow anyone to set and retrieve any data by key, but it seems too 'exposing' for a class library. Then `IDictionary Tag { get; }` would be a better option, but both allow anyone to clear the entire dictionary which I want to avoid. Then again, both HashTable and IDictionary only allow you to work with `object` instances, where something generic may be a better choice. But `Dictionary<?> Tag { get; }` is obviously not going to work for all possible consumers.

So, which way to go?

Edit:
As Timwi below correctly suggested, I don't want different user classes to be able to interfere with eachother. I assume a scenario where there are many entity classes and only a few classes which want to store associated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that one of your requirements is that the individual threads or processes that access an entity object should not be able to see each other’s private data. I’m afraid this is a pretty good indication that the private data should not be in the entity object which is shared by them. Instead, each process should have its own private data. It doesn’t have to be actually *in* the entity object itself, but it can be associated with the entity object via a private dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<Entity, object> myPrivateEntityData = new ...;
```

Furthermore, since this is now private to the process, and the process presumably knows exactly what kind of data it wants to associate with each Entity, you can now make it completely typesafe.

```
private Dictionary<Entity, SuperSecretSpecialData> myPrivateEntityData = new ...;

private sealed class SuperSecretData {
    public bool     NoOne;
    public int      ElseBut;
    public string   MeCan;
    public DateTime SeeThis;
}
```

There is some pain associated with having to check whether each entity is in the dictionary first, but you can fix this too. Personally I use a class `AutoDictionary` which simply extends `Dictionary` in such a way that it automatically creates objects when they are missing:

```
public sealed class AutoDictionary<TKey, TVal> : Dictionary<TKey, TVal> where TVal : class, new()
{
    public new TVal this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!ContainsKey(key))
                Add(key, new TVal());
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}

private AutoDictionary<Entity, SuperSecretSpecialData> myPrivateEntityData = new ...;
```

Then you can easily access `myPrivateEntityData[someEntity].NoOne` (etc.) and it will just work and never throw an exception because the key is not there, and yet you can still use `ContainsKey` if you *want* to check if it’s there.

Comment: But imagine the likely situation where there are many entity objects but only one or a few user classes storing associated data. Wouldn't it be faster to have a small dictionary for each entity than one large for each user? Yes, this results in many small dictionaries. Maybe, under the assumption that a user class may want to store a reference for almost every entity, some compromise can be found?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
public class Taggable :ITaggable
    {
        private IDictionary<string, object> _tags = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public void AddTag(string key, object tag)
        {
            _tags.Add(key,tag);
        }

        public bool IsTag(string key)
        {
            return _tags.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public T GetTag<T>(string key)
        {
            return (T) _tags[key];
        }
        public void RemoveTag(string key)
        {
            _tags.Remove(key);
        }
    }
```

Although I have not included it, all four methods are on the interface.

No one can 'abuse' the collection as they would need to know the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `IDictionary` or `Dictionary` to make it mutable. However something tells me that you're probably going about this wrong in general. Loosely typed collections are always fun on the delivery end...

That's just my 2c, kind of subjective, but I avoid loose types unless they're necessary.